# Can I give a Shape or other object a custom property, like "MyCustomID"?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can I give elements a custom property/attribute/field to store information about them in a simple way? Like myobject.parentid (parentid being a number set by me when the object is created, and then retrieved later via myobject.parentid when this object is interacted with).

Or is storing info like that in myobject.Name or myobject.Tag the simplest way?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is with an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) in WPF.

An attached property allows you to create any arbitrary property and associate it with an element. You can then use it to store data and participate in binding scenarios.

```
public class MyCustomIdSource
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomIdProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyCustomId", typeof(Int32), typeof(MyCustomIdSource));

    public static void SetMyCustomId(UIElement element, Int32 value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MyCustomIdProperty, value);
    }

    public static Int32 GetMyCustomId(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Int32)element.GetValue(MyCustomIdProperty);
    }
}
```

You may, however, want to give consideration to what you are accomplishing by putting custom data in the WPF element itself. Do you really want to have the element have responsibility for this? Would it make more sense to separate that responsibility into a class which maintains logic and state for the view and then bind the view to it? This is know as the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern, and is well suited to WPF development.

Comment: You're right with everything you say about attached properties, and i would also recommend to use them because of type safety. But if you're seriously looking for the simplest way to store additional information on a FrameworkElement, imo that would be the `Tag` property.

Comment: @Clemens - you know, you're right, that would be the simplest to start with (I didn't even know there was still a `Tag` property), but it doesn't take long for the ongoing maintenance of the data in that property to overwhelm any notion of "simple." I remember what a quick high and what a bitter crash using that deceptively simple property was in the days of VB *shudder*.

Comment: Thanks :) That does look like what I had in mind. It may be too complex to be worthwhile? I may need to explain a little more... I'm creating objects dynamically in code. When one of them is interacted with, I'll want to know if it has a "parentid" or other small properties like "id" "datasize" "url" etc. It seems simpler to put these in a Name/Tag, unless I am missing something? Ex: object.Name = "9_2_24". .... Otherwise it would have to be requested from the original source (ie. database) each time. If "myObject.parentid" would be ideal though...

Comment: @Ael - honestly if I were you I'd just build a specific class to hold all those properties and then use the `DataContext` property to store them, so that I can optionally bind them to and display them on the view. This is the heart of MVVM...